# Veeam Back jobs failing with error: Error: Client error: ChannelError: ConnectionReset

Tags: backup, vmware-vcenter, veeam

My Veeam Backup was working fine until one day I got this error:

> Error: Client error: ChannelError: ConnectionReset

I was having this error for every backup job(new and old) and restore job.
The configuration is: Windows Server 2008 R2 as vCenter and Veeam Backup Server and 2 ESXi hosts on a shared NAS.

Answer (score 1):

Since it took me some hours to solve this issue the real problem was that on that server I have installed **Symantec System Recovery** (**Symantec Backup Exec** produce the same problem) and on that day I have uninstalled it.
It seems that **Veeam** and **Symantec** are using some shared files/services so by uninstalling the Symantec it breaks the Veeam configuration.

Since the error explanation point on "Network issue" the solution is to run these 2 files: **VeeamTransport.msi**, **vPowerNFS.msi** and repair the installation. You can find them on this path: `C:\Program Files\Veeam\Backup and Replication\Backup\Packages`